# What does session_cache_limiter(false) do?

Tags: php, caching

On the `session_cache_limiter()` documentation page, several options are given for values that can be passed to the function.

But none of them is a boolean. I'm now seeing `session_cache_limiter(false);` in some legacy code I'm working on, and I'm curious about what it does. Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible values for `session_cache_limiter()` are :
 `public`, `private_no_expire`, `private` and `nocache`

If it's `false` it will not add one of the following header : Expires, Cache-Control, Last-Modified.

You can test it by calling `session_start()` and check the HTTP Headers from the Dev tools of your browser.

https://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php